Unable to install python-poppler on Windows for pdftotext
I am trying to install poppler on Windows for Python as I want to use pdftotext.
I have referred to several SO posts like:

cannot install pdftotext on windows because of poppler
How to install Poppler on Windows?

I have downloaded the poppler files from this source.
Even after several fixes of CMAKE I am still getting below error:

Seems like it is not able to find poppler-cpp files even when I have put this poppler folder in Program Files and have added PATH
I have added Path to Environment variables:

files structure: C:\Program Files\poppler-24.07.0\Library\bin

file structure: C:\Program Files\poppler-24.07.0\Library\lib

I have also restarted the machine after setting PATH.
What else should I do to make this work?

Have you tried changing the file name for example?
"C:\Program Files\poppler\Library\lib"
In my case it was the solution.

Thanks for the suggestion. I couldn't try that as I finally ended up running Ubuntu on windows 11 and used apt commands and updated MSVC toolset C++, Visual C++ which fixed everything.
